# Using JavaScript to read a JSON feed from Solr on a remote server- how is it actually done?

Tags: javascript, json, solr, jsonp

I cannot seem to get this to work, I have heard rumours that you actually need a jsonp object.

Does anybody have a code snippet for reading a JSON feed from Solr on a remote server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$.getJSON("http://remotehost:8080/solr/select/?q=jaberwocky&wt=json&json.wrf=?", function(result){
 alert("hello" + result.response.docs[0].name);
});
</script>
```

The complicated bit is understanding nameless callbacks in this case json.wrf=?. Basically if you add json.wrf=? to your solr url it will start working

JSONP *appears* to be a red herring in this instance

Comment: Your answer is wrong.  JSONP is *not* a red herring.  The json.wrf parameter expects the name of a JSONP callback.  If you use the ? shortcut, jQuery provides an internal name for you.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen- Could you give a solution to demonstrate your point?

Answer (score 3):

The first result for "solr jsonp" gives [Solr and JSONP](http://xplus3.net/2010/09/21/solr-and-jsonp/).  Does that work for you?

EDIT: To show this is just JSONP, and using the [question mark replacement](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp) is optional (but convenient), you can just use `getScript` and your own callback:

```
function my_callback(response)
{

}

$.getScript("http://remotehost:8080/solr/select/?q=jaberwocky&wt=json&json.wrf=my_callback");
```

You don't even need jQuery.  You could do the same thing by manually creating and appending a `<script>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSONP for jQuery](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/) for jQuery JSONP requests. You can use it easily to read data from remote server.